# Function inside a loop

Tags: php, html, loops

I have a for loop for table row and table data. What I just want is to add class name on every  table data but of course they will not be the same class name.

But the problem is the output of the function is placing outside the table. I already check the Quotes or something, but still it is placing outside. Anyone can explain to me why?

```
function alphaCount(){
  for ($i=65; $i<=90; $i++) {
    echo char($i);
  }
  for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++) {
    echo '<td  class="char-'.$i.'-'.$this->alphaCount.'"> </td>';
  }
```

Comment: what table? I cannot see one

Comment: That is quite the typo...

Comment: @Ferhad It's in the text of the question. He must had a hard time formatting the codes.

Comment: I reformatted your code without fixing it. Please check if its correct.

Comment: Missing } somewhere in that code

Comment: Lilmer - you wrote `$this->alphaCunt` instead of `alphaCount`. Back in a Flash's edit changed that - make sure your own code has `count` instead of `cunt` too...

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, I don't get much of your code but according to the problem you described, I guess the problem is following.

You have a function that generates some identifier, but it echoes it instead of returning it, like this:

```
function getId() {
  // something
  echo $id;
}
```

And when you are generating the entry, you are having following code:

```
echo "<tr class='" . getId() . "'>...</tr>";
```

Like that the `getId()` method echoes the identifier before the `<tr>` tag is rendered. You can resolve it either by changing the echo statement in `getId` to the return statement, or you can rewrite your entry generator in following way:

```
echo "<tr class='"
getId();
echo "'>...</tr>";
```

I hope this is what you had a problem with.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the resulting HTML source (from "view source" in browser), you will see that it is invalid:

```
abcdefg...
<td class="char-1-?"> </td>
<td class="char-2-?"> </td>
...
```

What you output in the first loop is outside of any table cell. Browsers will handle that as if it was completely outside the table.

*Edit: it might also be that you screwed your brackets in the question and your real code does something totally different. Hard to tell from the original formatting.*